# Retrofit response is getting Null when typed wrong details

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

in login form-->when typed correct user details like email and password it is successfully taking me to next activity but when typed wrong details Retrofit response is getting Null

in postman -->error message is showing properly 
but not in app toast it is showing null

here is my activity-->

```
RetrofitClient.instance.userLogin(email, password)
  .enqueue(object : Callback<LoginResponse> {
override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
   Log.d("res", "" + t)
            }

 override fun onResponse(
   call: Call<LoginResponse>,
       response: Response<LoginResponse>
        ) {
            var res = response

            Log.d("response check ", "" + response.body()?.status.toString())
            if (res.body()?.status==200) {
  SharedPrefManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
                 .saveUser(response.body()?.data!!)

             val intent = Intent(applicationContext, HomeActivity::class.java)
             intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
             Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            res.body()?.message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()
              } else {
                //Log.d("res", "" +  res.body()?.status.toString())
                Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext, (res.body()?.status.toString())
                            ,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                 ).show()
           }
```

thanks in advance
help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got answer:

```
      val jObjError =JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                            Toast.makeText(
                                applicationContext,
                                jObjError.getString("message")+jObjError.getString("user_msg"),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show()
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                           Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            Log.e("errorrr",e.message)
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
res.code()
```

Instead of,

```
res.body()?.status
```

Comment: by filling incorect data and added your code i got -->   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x191..app crashes

Comment: You need to set the int as a String lime `"$status" `

Comment: I said you have to convert the status code into a String before you display it in a TextView. Unless it is a string resource identifier, which this is not.

Comment: i converted into string...still im getting null written in toast when typed wrong details @EpicPandaForce

Comment: hey genesis and @EpicPandaForce ..i still havent found the answer could you please help me out